# Returning 404 code for unauthorized attempts

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess

I have an admin directory on my web server (http://test.com/admin) and I don't want unauthorized parties to access this /admin/ directory instead I want to return 404 error code for all unauthorized accesses.

My question is, is there any way to return 404 error code for all access attempts except a few specific IP addresses?

My web server is Apache on Linux (plesk).

Comment: Presumably you're choosing to deliberately hide the resource rather than return a 403?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, close:

```
<Location /admin>
     Order deny,allow
     Allow from 10.0.0.1
     Allow from 192.168.1.1
     Deny from all
</Location>
```

Though what this actually does is return a 403 Forbidden, not a 404 Not Found, which is, y'know, correct.

If you're putting this in a .htaccess in the admin directory, you don't need the Location container.  The example is written for a server or virtual host configuration file.

See also mod_access docs.

For what it's worth, as time has worn on I've increasingly come to find value in putting the site admin on an entirely separate virtual host.

Answer (score 15):

You can use mod_rewrite to do that.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=10.0.0.1 [OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=10.0.0.1
RewriteRule ^admin($|/) - [L,R=404]
```

Note that the `R=404` flag requires at least Apache 2.1.1.

Comment: This is brilliant for *properly* hiding `.htaccess`, etc., not to mention `WEB-INF` when fronting for a servlet container and keeping everything in the same source directory. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

check the "allow from" attribute in the configuration guide

Answer (score 0):

Under `litespeed` the following small variation with `mod_rewrite` worked for me:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^1.2.3.4 [OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^1.2.3.4
RewriteRule (.*) - [R=404,L]
```