# Apache - Return 404 for all execept selected

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

I am seeking for method to prevent access to Wordpress admin folder "wp-admin", but also i need apache to generate 404 error (Not found) for all, but not selected IPs.
I found this post [Returning 404 code for unauthorized attempts](https://serverfault.com/questions/13068/returning-404-code-for-unauthorized-attempts) and tried Rewrite solution, but does not work for me.

So i keeping all websites in /usr/local/www/apache22/data
and tried to use such config in httpd.conf (Apache2.2 FreeBSD 9.1)

```
<Directory "/usr/local/www/apache22/data">
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=77.120.9.3 [OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=77.120.9.5
RewriteRule ^wp-admin($|/) - [L,R=404]
</Directory>
```

For example, location of wp-admin for website is: /usr/local/www/apache22/data/doman.com/wp-admin

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Why isn't simply denying access (HTTP/403) for unauthorized IP addresses (which you can do with simple `Allow`/`Deny` rules) adequate?

Comment: I have been awaiting for such reply. The reason is to obfuscate bad bots trying to guess presence of Wordpress installed. So if they get 404 error then they won't try to explore for wordpress vulnerabilities.

Comment: is it not possible to actually MOVE the wp-admin stuff? If you can just move the file/folder to a new location you get your 404, your obfuscation, and you aren't doing absolutely silly (breaking internet standards) things to do it...

Comment: To answer my own questions: Can't move wp-admin...easily... with that said, lets move on... WHERE have you added the above code? httpd.conf? .htaccess? is mod_rewrite reloaded and enabled in apache? have you restarted apache since you made the changes? edit the question with your responses and we will go from there.

Comment: I mentioned in question already where i have added rules. Sure restarted apache, mod_rewrite loaded http://pastebin.com/b65GhsVZ and working fine as plenty of my website using it. Regarding moving wp-admin, sure i can use bash script to rename all in one shot, but i'm curious (and actually going to use) how to accomplish this without touching core files.

Answer (score 1):

OK, First let me say that your entire premise is flawed: There are *many* other ways besides the presence of `/wp-admin` to determine that you're using Wordpress. You're attempting [Security through Obscurity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity), and since you're not obscuring everything you aren't doing a particularly elegant job of it.

---

Those inherent problems aside, at a quick glance your `RewriteRule` seems to be wrong.
Per [the Apache documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html):

> **What is matched?**
>
> In VirtualHost context, The Pattern will initially be matched against the part of the URL after the hostname and port, and before the query string (e.g. "/app1/index.html").
>
> In Directory and htaccess context, the Pattern will initially be matched against the filesystem path, after removing the prefix that led the server to the current RewriteRule (e.g. "app1/index.html" or "index.html" depending on where the directives are defined).

Simply put that means you need more of the path to `wp-admin` in your rule if you want to do this in the `Directory` context (like `^domain.com/wp-admin($|/)`). The simple/naive fix would be to change your regex to `^.*wp-admin($|/)` and just match *anything* that contains `wp-admin` (which is also a good way to verify that the rule itself is being parsed).

If you insist on pursuing this avenue of "security" though I would advise making this change in the `VirtualHost` context (or `/wp-admin/.htaccess` file) instead of in the `Directory` context for your whole server. It is both simpler to write and more robust. (Your current solution breaks if someone on your server DOESN'T want their wordpress admin page locked down (and there are probably a lot of people who won't -- anyone with a dynamic IP for example). Doing this in each `VirtualHost` or a `.htaccess` file allows you to keep certain sites "unlocked".)

Comment: Hope I found what i need. This works for me if below block inserted in httpd.conf context

    <Directory /usr/local/www/apache22/data/*/wp-admin>
    RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^77\.120\.9\.3$
    RewriteRule . http://google.com/404.php [R=404,L]
    </Directory>

I saw this in Rewrite redirects examples and adapted to serve 404 error, but initially it was intended to do redirection.