# Stop processing and return to client immediatly in Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

I have a Apache 2.2 that hosts a proprietary (commercial) authentication module. That modules looks at every requests and might let them through if they are flagged and "anonymous ok" in the back-end authentication software.

One such anonymous resource is a small gif queried by the load balacer fronting our Apaches, named `/lb.gif`.

When there is a problem with the authentication software, its module does not take any chances and blocks everything, including our load-balancer beacon file. The load-balancer thinks the site is down and stops sending traffic to it.

I want Apache not to send this particular request to other modules. [This](https://serverfault.com/q/541651/81170) kind of works:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/lb.gif$ - [R=200]
```

Seeing this, Apache returns some HTML with a 200 result:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>200 OK</title>
</head><body>
<h1>OK</h1>
<p>The server encountered an unknown error, possibly due to misconfiguration.
Contact the server administrator: [no address given]<p>
More information about this error may be available
in the server error log.</p>
</body></html>
```

It satisfies the load-balancer, but confuses another tool we are using for monitoring.

Is there a way to tell Apache to stop processing and return immediately a resource, not sending the request further down the chain of modules?

Answer (score 1):

You might argue that the loadbalancer check failing when your authentication module is acting up is exactly what you need...

A work-around I have used in the past is setting up a separate VirtualHost in the Apache configuration, where you can disable authentication, and assuming that the loadbalancer http client sends a HTTP 1.1 Host header, validate the web server node uptime by polling that VirtualHost instead of your main site.

Comment: The thing is that a broken backend is hard to distinguish from a broken Apache or broken load-balancer. +1 for the workaround. It's a good idea, but we are using SSL terminated in Apache, without SNI extensions so virtual hosts will not work.