# Hiding a HTTP Auth-Realm by sending 404 to non-known IPs?

Tags: apache-2.2, http-basic-authentication

I have an Apache (2.2) serving a web-app on `example.com`. That web-app has a debug-page reachable via `example.com/debug`. `/debug` is currently protected with a HTTP basic auth. As there is only a very small user-base who has access to the debug-page, I would like to hide it based on IP address and return `404` to clients not accessing from our VPN.

Serving a 404 based on IP-address only is easy and is described in https://serverfault.com/a/13071.
But as soon I add authentication, the users see a `401` instead of a `404`.

Basically, what I need is:

```
if ($REMOTE_ADDR ~ 10.11.12.*):
  do_basic_auth (aka return 401)
else:
  return 404
```

**UPDATE** This works:

```
<VirtualHost ...>
...
SetEnvIf REMOTE_ADDR 10.128.0.* HAS_debug=1
SetEnvIf REMOTE_ADDR 10.128.1.* HAS_debug=1
SetEnvIf REMOTE_ADDR 10.128.2.* HAS_debug=1

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{ENV:HAS_debug} !=1
RewriteRule ^/debug($|/) - [R=404,L]

<Location /debug>
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "hidden-debug"
    AuthUserFile ...
    Require valid-user
</Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

The crucial part was rewriting *outside* of the `Location`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have/don't mind enabling mod_rewrite, you can hide the directory from unknown IPs by rewriting requests for the debug directory (in an .htaccess in the parent directory) to return a 404 if the IP is unknown, and leave a standard basic auth .htaccess in your debug directory for authenticating users who make it that far.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=<vpn ip>
RewriteRule ^debug($|/) - [L,R=404]
```

(This example lifted directly from [Returning 404 code for unauthorized attempts](https://serverfault.com/questions/13068/returning-404-code-for-unauthorized-attempts) found when I was googling for the exact syntax you'd need)

Comment: Interesting. This works inside a <VirtualHost> but not outside of it as I tried before.

Comment: That could be an allowoverride thing - your non-virtualhost config might not be allowing the use of mod_rewrite from .htaccess?

Comment: The config was in /etc/apache2/conf.d, so no .htaccess restrictions in use, and no errors about these.